# How check Pin state in code vision for atmega16

Tags: avr

I connect PORTC.3 with switch to 5v. in my code I do some thing in conditional block "if(PORTC.3)".in proteus I change state of switch but every time PORTC.3 is 0! what does event occur?

thanks...

Comment: Schematic and full code sample would help.

Comment: Did you set the pin as an input (using the data direction register)?

Comment: I resolve it, for input pin must use "if(PINC.3)" instead of PORTC.3.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to query the PIN register, specifically `PINC.3` for you.  Each port has one of these registers and it stores  the input data of the pin.

Make sure your pins are set as input at the `Data-Direction Register (DDR)`, in your case `DDRC` and you will need to set them low (logic 0) for them to be configured as an input.